# What is this barcode format?

Tags: format, barcode

I need to generate a CSV file in a specific format, but I have no idea what format this is. This is some kind of barcode string, but that's all I know.

```
<WnnwNNwwNnnnWWnnnWWnNnwwNnnWnWNnwnWWNnwnNwWnnnWnwNNnwwNnnNWwnnWNwnwnNWwnNwNnnWWnnNnWwNnwwNnWnwNnnWWnnnWWnnnWWn>
```

(This row has 112 `WNwn`s, removing the `<` and `>`)

Anyone know anything about this weird format? Google doesn't know anything either...

Comment: I feel like we are missing quite a bit of the backstory. In many cases wide and narrow bars and spaces are indicated by 'n's and 'w's, but the mixed case is throwing me. If capital 'W' means 4xn and lowercase 'w' means 3xn and uppercase 'N' means 2xn, then we may have something, but even when converting to 1's and 0's and printing the barcode assuming this, the barcode won'r scan, so I'm left with nothing as well.

Comment: That may be Kodac patch code for document scanners